# How to improve Search query efficiency in lucene?

Tags: lucene

I'm building a search for my application. For the entered search term (foo),

> 1)  I look for exact match (foo), if it returns NULL
>
> 2)  I use fuzzy search (foo~), if it returns NULL
>
> 3)  I use wildcard (foo*).

Is this an efficient way? Or is there any `lucene` method to do all these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way of doing this in the Lucene. However, usually this case is handled outside of the Lucene in client-side. Yes, from my experience it's very efficient, since it's usually provides high precision results. In some sources over the internet it's called staged search

E.g. you create a query for exact match, let's say **TermQuery("field","foo")**, if this query return nothing, than you use FuzzyQuery and last one PrefixQuery (I will recommend it over WildcardQuery, for the last case you want to do)